# Find image tag variants of a given tag

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

If I run this:

```
$ docker search node
```

I get some results in the terminal:

```
NAME                                   DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
node                                   Node.js is a JavaScript-based platform for s…   5716                [OK]                
mhart/alpine-node                      Minimal Node.js built on Alpine Linux           363                                     
mongo-express                          Web-based MongoDB admin interface, written w…   261                 [OK]                
nodered/node-red-docker                Node-RED Docker images.                         157                                     [OK]
iojs                                   io.js is an npm compatible platform original…   126                 [OK]                
prom/node-exporter                                                                     77                                      [OK]
```

my question is - is there a command I can use to find all the variants of the first result?

I am looking to get a list of all the images/tags like so:

```
[
   "node:4.2",
   "node:5.1",
   "node:5.3",
   "node:5.45",
   "node:5.7",
   "node:6.2",
   "node:7",
   "node:8",
   "node:9",
   // ...
   "node:10"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Docker search doesn't have this feature**

What you can do instead is use a simple `curl` command combine with `jq` :

```
https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/<NAME>/tags
```

Example :

```
curl https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/node/tags | jq -r '.[].name'
```

Will return all the tags :

```
...
chakracore-8.11
chakracore-8.11.1
chakracore-8.9
chakracore-8.9.4
jessie
onbuild
slim
stretch
wheezy
```

And If you want to get **all tags of all result** :

```
for i in $(docker search --format {{.Name}} node); do
    echo "All tag for image : $i"
    curl https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$i/tags | jq -r '.[].name'
done
```

Or **all tag of the first result** :

```
name=$(docker search --limit 1 --format {{.Name}} node)
curl https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/$name/tags | jq -r '.[].name'
```

Comment: You need to authenticate https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/
More example here > https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1968#issuecomment-248452211